# Show that $\int_{|x|<R}\frac{|f(x)|}{|x|}\mathrm dx=o(R),\quad R\to\infty.$

Tags: inequality, integral-inequality

> Suppose $f\in L^3(\mathbb R^3)$. Show that $$\int_{|x|<R}\frac{|f(x)|}{|x|}\mathrm dx=o(R),\quad R\to\infty.$$

First, I try to show that for a fixed $R_0$, $\int_{|x|<R_0}\frac{|f(x)|}{|x|}\mathrm dx<\infty$. This follows from Hölder's inequality:
$$\int_{|x|<R_0}\frac{|f(x)|}{|x|}\mathrm dx\le\left(\int_{|x|<R_0}|f(x)|^3\mathrm dx\right)^{1/3}\left(\int_{|x|<R_0}\frac{\mathrm dx}{|x|^{3/2}}\right)^{2/3}.$$
But it can only yield 
$$\int_{|x|<R}\frac{|f(x)|}{|x|}\mathrm dx=O(R),\quad R\to\infty.$$

How can I improve my result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$, and let $R_{\epsilon}$ satisfy $\int\limits_{|x|>R_{\epsilon}}{|f(x)|^3\text{ d}x}<\epsilon^3$. For $R>R_{\epsilon}$, have
\begin{align} \int\limits_{|x|<R}{\frac{|f(x)|}{|x|}\text{ d}x}&=\int\limits_{|x|<R_{\epsilon}}{\frac{|f(x)|}{|x|}\text{ d}x} + \int\limits_{R_{\epsilon}\le |x|<R}{\frac{|f(x)|}{|x|}\text{ d}x} \\
&\le C_{\epsilon} + \left(\,\int\limits_{R_{\epsilon}\le|x|<R}{|f(x)|^3\text{ d}x}\,\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}\left(\,\int\limits_{R_{\epsilon}\le|x|<R}{\frac{1}{|x|^{\frac{3}{2}}}}\,\right)^{\frac{2}{3}} \\
&\le C_{\epsilon} + \left(\,\int\limits_{|x|>R_{\epsilon}}{|f(x)|^3\text{ d}x}\,\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}\left(\,\int\limits_{|x|<R}{\frac{1}{|x|^{\frac{3}{2}}}}\,\right)^{\frac{2}{3}} \\
&\le C_{\epsilon} + C\epsilon R
\end{align}
and hence
$$ \limsup\limits_{R\rightarrow\infty}{\frac{1}{R}\int\limits_{|x|<R}{\frac{|f(x)|}{|x|}\text{ d}x}}\le C\epsilon. $$
Letting $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$ gives the desired result.

Comment: Really the same argument as what I posted. Which is not a complaint or a criticism, just a comment for the benefit of readers who find one easier to follow than the other (I can imagine that going either way, depending on the reader)...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I don't see it as "really" the same argument as here Joey is not using the density of functions with compact support. I see this proof as more straight forward.

Comment: I can understand your seeing it as more straightforward; that's why one might prefer his version (seems to me his is just more detailed, which is one reason one might prefer his and also why another one might prefer mine). But yes he does use the density of the functions with compact support. Implicitly, anyway. Right at the start, where he chooses $R_\epsilon$ so $\int_{|x|>R_\epsilon}|f|^3<\epsilon^3$. The existence of such an $R_\epsilon$ is exactly equivalent to the density of the functions with compact support.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net See edit - I inserted yet another presentation, trying to bridge the gap.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** I've claimed that the arguments in the two answers are in some sense really the same. People have disputed this. I think it's a Good Thing for a person to see how it is that they *are* really the same. A Good Thing because if you like one better than the other, or find one easier to follow, then in the future when you see another argument presented in the style you don't prefer you'll be better able to understand it by seeing how it's the same as an argument you do prefer.

So I'm going to give a second version of my proof; I think it will be clear that my second version is really the same as my first version, while it may be more clear how my second version is really the same as Joey Zou's presentation.

**Original:**

Let $$\phi(f,R)=\frac1R\int_{|x|\le R}\frac{|f(x)|}{|x|}\,dx.$$You've shown that $$\phi(f,R)\le c||f||_3.$$

If $f$ has compact support then certainly  $$\lim_{R\to\infty}\phi(f,R)=0.$$
In general, choose $f_n$ with compact support such that $||f_n-f||_3\to0$.Then $$\phi(f_n,R)\to\phi(f,R)\quad(n\to\infty)$$_uniformly_ in $R$; hence $\lim_{R\to\infty}\phi(f,R)=0$.

**Revised:** This is the same as above, except instead of *using* the fact about uniform convergence that's used above I don't mention uniform convergence, instead inserting and using the *proof* of said fact about uniform convergence:

Let $$\phi(f,R)=\frac1R\int_{|x|\le R}\frac{|f(x)|}{|x|}\,dx.$$You've shown that $$\phi(f,R)\le c||f||_3.$$

If $f$ has compact support then certainly  $$\lim_{R\to\infty}\phi(f,R)=0.$$

In general, suppose that $f\in L^3$ and $\epsilon>0$. Choose $g$ with compact support so that $$||f-g||_3<\epsilon.$$ Now $$|\phi(f,R)-\phi(g,R)|<C\epsilon$$for every $R$; since $\phi(g,R)\to0$ this shows that $$\limsup_{R\to\infty}\phi(f,R)\le C\epsilon.$$Since $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary, $\phi(f,R)\to0$.

Comment: I like both proofs.

Comment: @EclipseSun So do I. mathcounterexamples comment notwithstanding, I do think there's something to be learned by trying to see how they really _are_ the same argument, presented very differently. Of course "really the same" is fuzzy enough that it's not something one can prove, but there _is_ a meaningful bijection between the steps in this proof and in that proof. Or so it seems to me.

Comment: @EclipseSun Revised: Changed two proofs to three proofs, in an attempt to show how there's really only one here.